# Which equation of a Butterfly?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-geometry, curves

Let $A, B$ be two points and $L$ be a line on the [Euclidean Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry). Take two points $J, G$ on the line $L$ such that $JG=constant$. Let $AJ$ meet $BG$ at $P$, $AG$ meet $BJ$ at $Q$, then the locus of points $P, Q$ is a conic when $J$ is moved on the line $L$, namely the [Steiner Conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_conic).

[image]

If we replace the line $L$ by a conic, the Locus of points $P, Q$ is very nice. In some cases, the Locus looks like a [Butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly). In some cases the locus has is made of two pieces:

> Which is the equation of this locus?

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS: In the figure I take $JG = arc JG \approx constant $ (Because defect of software)